# Show/Hide (Toggle) a table inside a table on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor, html-table

I have two different tables where one of the table is populated based on the value of the first table. Currently the result table is rendered in a new page. But I want the table to be populated on link click in the next row of the original table.

**View for the first table**

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Option Name</th>
        <th>Technical Characteristic</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Options)
    {
        <tr>
            <td data-toggle="tooltip" title="@item.DescriptionDE">@Html.ActionLink(item.OptionName, "ViewOptionValues", "OptionValues", new { id = item.OptionID }, null)</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink(@item.TechnicalCharacteristic.TCName, "ViewTcSet", "TechnicalCharacteristics", new {id = item.TechnicalCharacteristicID },null)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("View Properties", "ViewOptionvalues", "Options", new { id = item.OptionID }, null)|
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.OptionID })|
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.OptionID })|
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.OptionID })
            </td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>
```

The click on `ActionLink(View Properties)` will generate the following table

```
<table class="table" style="table-layout:fixed">
    <tr>           
        <th>Option Values</th>           
        @foreach (var tc in Model.TechnicalCharacteristic.TcSets.OrderBy(x => x.SetName))
        {
            <th>
                @tc.SetName
            </th>
        }
    </tr>
    @foreach (var ov in Model.OptionValues)
    {
        var link = false;
        <tr>
            <th>@ov.OptionVal</th>
            @foreach (var s in Model.TechnicalCharacteristic.TcSets.OrderBy(x => x.SetName))
            {
                int count = 1;                    
                foreach (var sv in ov.SetValue)
                {
                    if (sv.TcSetID == s.TcSetID)
                    {
                        count = 0;
                        <td>@sv.Value</td>
                    }
                }
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    <td class="alert-danger">Missing Values</td>
                    link = true;

                }
            }
            @if(link==true)
            {
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Add missing properties", "Create", "SetValues", new {@id=ov.OptionValueID },null)</td>
            }

        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**What I tried**

I tried to add an extra row in the forloop in the main table and set it to hidden. But the `tr style= display:hidden` isn't valid. I have done the same with `div`. Here I do not know how I could pass the parameter to the function that populates the second table and how to render it.

**Update**

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("View Properties", "ViewOptionvalues", "Options", new { id = item.OptionID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="ViewProperty"})
```

Now I have the table being displayed in the `<tr> <td><div id="ViewProperty"></div></td></tr>`. But always only the first `<div>` is being populated.

**Scripts**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#links').click(function () {
        $('.View').toggle();

    });
});
</script>
```

where `links` is the class for the `<td>` that hold the `AjaxActionLink` and `View` is the class for the `<tr>` which holds the div. The table is being toggled but the table is displayed always after the first row.

I also tried `this.next()` but it did not display anything.

Comment: You should use `display:none` instead of hidden. Try with that.

Comment: OK. `display:None` is right. Still I have no way to render the second table into that particular row.

Comment: You need to run an ajax call by clicking on that action link and just replace its response in hidden tr element and then show it.

Comment: So i should change the `Html.ActionLink` to `Ajax.ActionLink` ?

Comment: You could do this both way if you use normal action link then you have to register its client event via JS/jQuery thereafter run the ajax with its href and get the response. On another way (Ajax.ActionLink) you will have its delegate like onSuccess so you can use that. Choice is yours !!

Comment: OK. Now i have the table being populated. But it is not being populated inside the row properly. So now I added a div to get the table populated. I will update the question with the current code. But I want it to be viewwed below the corresponding row that is being clicked

Comment: you have to play around with jQuery/JS.

Comment: I have done this when I had the div already populated and I could toggle on button click. Here i do not know how I could achieve the same. i am not sure what property needs to be accessed in the Jquery

Comment: ok, add that code in your question.

Comment: Added the Jquery code. See the updated question.